# UI design challenge for this situation

Tags: php, javascript, user-interface

**Screenshot mockup:** http://tinypic.com/r/y2qex/5

**Problem:** I have a table that has 53 columns; one for each week of the year, plus one with the user name. It will have anywhere between 10 and 80 rows, depending on the number of users for each area.

The users need to be set a “flag” for each week, such as Annual Leave, Training etc.

I currently have a table, which has a select box in each cell. The problem is this works for 5 rows, but once I start getting 20+ rows, the browser wont open the page, because there are just too many select boxes.

Whatever new selections are picked must be able to be queried, so I can save them in my DB.

What I’m after are some generic ideas (i.e. not specific code) on how I can better solve this problem. Once I get a good idea, I’ll go off an work out the exact coding.

My ideas so far:
- Make all cells text only, with the current selection, then have an ‘edit’ option beside each user, which opens their row as a modal window which can be editted
- Make all cells have a “onClick” event, causing a dropdown list to be generated at the point of click

But I’d be keen to hear how other people might approach/solve this problem?

Comment: I think your idea might work, maybe adding a dropdown list instead of select will be fine too, since you don't have to worry about binding both the edit event and the change event for each cell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the options are the same for many select boxes, you could consider using one datalist for all of them, this would be more performant, and I'm guessing allow you to have more per page. Unfortunately this is an HTML 5 feature, so it would not be backwards compatible with all browsers.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_datalist.asp

Other than that, you could consider pagenating your table if it gets over a certain number of columns. Or do like a tumbr thing, where more columns load via ajax if they scroll to the right far enough. You idea also should work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at using a calendar feature, I'm sure there's a ton of Javascript calendars out there.  I also have had a lot of success lately using DataTables.  You could use DataTables + jEditable to create a click to edit table representation, that when clicked gives you a select box, but otherwise shows only text.

Comment: yeah - i thought about that, but the calender is too obstructive, so the table seems to look better. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could have a single hidden select box on the page and display it on a cell when clicked, and handle the result of the click by writing a data-attribute to the cell, and perhaps doing a simultaneous XHR?

You could also just have a bunch of hidden form elements, but that would be gross.

Implementation-wise, you could do it with a single event handler attached to the table, with each cell having data-attributes representing name and week.

Anyway, this should be performant, even though it would require an extra 20 or so lines of js.

Comment: Thinking about it, this is just implementation-different from "onclick" on every cell. You shouldn't do that, though, you should attach the event to the table and use event propagation and the "target" attribute to figure out how to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work for you:

```
var td=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i<td.length; i++)
{
    td[i].id='cellID_'+i; 
    td[i].onclick=function()
    {
        //make menu appear on this element id
    }
}
```